# How to properly test in React Native

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I am having a hard time understanding the ways to propertly set up react-native for testing. Given that TDD is a big thing, I dont get it why is it not out of the box for react.

I am using babel 7, jest 24 and react native 0.62. At my first attempt to run `npm test`, I end up with errors which seem to be about node_modules not being in pure javascript. I am learning about transpilers and why we need them, but maybe I am missing something.

This is the kind of thing I am getting into:

```
    /Users/marcelo/work/projectname/javascript/ProjectName/node_modules/react-navigation/src/index.js:1
    ({"Object.<anonymous>":function(module,exports,require,__dirname,__filename,global,jest){export * from '@react-navigation/core';

    SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'export'
```

I did try to find something online about properly setting up the env for testing, but no luck so far. It seems this is not a well enough explored topic or I just dont know how to search. So how do I go about properly not only fixing this error, but setting up a decent TDD, BDD environment for my react native apps, whether it is component testing or UI testing?

Comment: Please share the file you're trying to test (all of it). Looks like you didn't mock something.